# Log internet requests made by vpn client

Tags: vpn, logging, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I log the requests that people make to the internet when they are connected to my VPN?

If one of them does something illegal, I need to be able to prove that it was not me, but a VPN client.

This really is a just in case type thing.

So, I want to be able to see the details (server, port, domain name, and time connected) in a file somewhere. Does windows offer this with its PPTP VPN service, or is there 3rd party software to do this (Free is better)?

**EDIT**

I have setup accounting, but that does not seem to tell me what I am looking for. Could someone comment on what accounting does?

**EDIT 2**

Maybe I should heve been clearer.

My system is running windows server 2008 r2 and using the stock VPN software (PPTP)

Comment: Unfortunately the answer to your question depends entirely on the VPN software and hardware combination you're using, as every system would have its own method (if at all) of tracking such actions.

Comment: @mikebabcock Maybe I should have mentioned it in the question (which I will do) but I have tagged the question as windows server 2008 r2 and it uses the stock VPN software.

Comment: Sorry, Can't help you on that one.  Good luck though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really related to the VPN connection.

You can install a transparent proxy which proxies and logs all internet connections and (depending on the software) filter out only those who have a source IP which is in the PPTP VPN IP address range.

The other option would be a TCP traffic logger, but it's more difficult to find out the actual connection parameters.

Comment: Do you know of any transparent proxies that might work well on windows? This sounds very do-able.

Comment: Well, [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is certainly the most well-known. You can get the Windows version here: http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/